# SSL in CodeIgniter cannot locate model

Tags: codeigniter, ssl

I am adding SSL to a working site.

My cert is installed correctly (verified by the GeoTrust test page).

The root of the site comes up correctly using https.
But if I go to another page, then I get 'Unable to connect'.

I am using this approach to ssl: http://nigel.mcbryde.com.au/2009/03/working-with-ssl-in-codeigniter/ and have also tried http://www.davidnard.com/2011/04/easy-ssl-redirection-in-codeigniter/ I get the same result with each.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have HTTPS in your `base_url` configuration?

in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://someurl.com';
```